# how to create form on infopath for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm very new to share point. I want to create a train ticket booking form, which will allow requester to enter their no. of tickets, journey date, number of travelers and then a submit button , once they press the submit, our general office should get  a notification that some one has requested to book a ticket . How can i achieve that?  any help will be very helpful,

I will use infopath to create form.

Kind Regards,

Biswa

Comment: @AndrewRidgway thats not the answer. I have already mentioned how can i achieve , im blank, i no nothing about sharepoint. I would have appriciated if you had guided me.

Comment: @AndrewRidgway If you dont have knowledge about the stuff i'm taking please do not make fun of others. I know you just want to earn reputation  by trolling with your ignorant comments. I have already reported you. I have asked question and you make fun of it ?? by saying "You pretty much just do it" ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create Infopath form with all your required fields.
2. Publish the Infopath form on a SharePoint library.
3. Configure Submit operation in Infopath form.
4. Publish form again. (Use quick publish this time because you want to publish on same library)
5. Open SharePoint Designer and create a List Workflow for this library.
6. Set this workflow to run when then item is created.
7. In workflow, you can add statements to send email to your "General Office"

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have manged it last week, As i was not getting any reply, i posted my answer to sharepoint.stackoverflow.com and got reply. Thanks for your answer too, i will mark it and close it